# Arc removal and completing the rectangle using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV to convert the given image into resulting image as shown in the attached image. I used Highline to detect edges but I'm unable to complete the rectangle/square and remove the arcs.

[image]

This is the original image.
[image: Original Image]

This is something i achieved using erosion and dilation. 
[image]

Comment: Do you need the actual positions of the lines or just a picture of the rough outlines?

Comment: I need exactly like the result image. For example it can be done by removing the arc and completing the square and if there are double line then convert them into single line.

Comment: You could just apply erode/dilate until the thin lines are gone. Then it gets more difficult, for example the top right rooms, the center is a room, the one on the right not. You need to come up with your own algorithm to detect those.

Comment: Can you post the original and result image separately?

Comment: Also the watermark makes everything harder to work with. Just with dilation and a threshold I was getting good results

Comment: @user8408080 Can you share it?

Comment: @Christoffer Yes.

Comment: @A.Raw [here](https://imgur.com/a/4QlR5Vt) is an example of what you could achieve with dilation, but I don't think, that this is your expected result, so I didn't post it as an answer

Comment: @user8408080 Yeah it looks good can you share the code too?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to identify (x,y) of line segment endpoints.

Run [Sobel](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d) or sepFilter2D over the source image to pick out vertical and horizontal edges separately. You might also use [HoughCircles](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) to locate and erase the door arcs. A filter that turns three parallel lines into a single fat line would certainly help you to handle windows.

Given a set of line segments that have (approximate) x,y labels, identify segment pairs that are close to being colinear and have an appropriately sized gap, corresponding to a door. Merge them, filling in the gap. Render the segments onto a blank image, or perhaps a faded version of the original image.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't post this as an answer first, because I don't think it's complete, but as you asked for the code in the comments, here it is.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("room.png", 0)
cv2.imshow("original", img)

kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow("dilated", dilation)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresholded", thresh)
```

It's just basic dilation and using the fact that diluted thin black lines will become grey, so that I can apply a threshold.

Result:
[image: result]

Of course you can play around with the parameters a bit, to get better results, but you won't get your expected result this way.